# how to show complete month dates and amount in php?

Tags: php, mysql, date

i want to make an xml string in php,

i want when transaction `date=$dates` then transaction date and thier related amount show from database and

if transaction `date!=$dates` then `$date` stored in label and amount=0 how i do this

here is my php code:

```
    <?php
function default1()
{
     $dates = array();
     $timestamp = time();
     for ($i = 1 ; $i <=30 ; $i++) 
     {
        $dates[$i]= date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) . '<br />';
        $timestamp -= 24 * 3600;
     }

        print_r ($dates);
    //echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));
        $strQuery="select Distinct DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y') as transaction_date,sum(amount)as Amount from transactions group by  DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y')";       
        $result = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($strQuery) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
        $strXML = "<chart caption='Reports of transactions' xAxisName='Date' yAxisName='Amount' showValues='0' useRoundEdges='1' palette='3'>";
        while($ors = $result->fetch_assoc ())
        {
            for ($i = 1 ; $i <=30 ; $i++)
            {
                if(in_array("'".$ors['transaction_date']."'", $dates[$i]))
                {
                    $strXML .= "<set label='" .$ors['transaction_date'] ."' value='" . $ors['Amount'] ."' />";
                }
                else
                {
                    $strXML .= "<set label='" .$dates."' value='0' />";
                }
            }
        }
        $strXML .= "</chart>";
        ?>
        <textarea><? print_r($strXML); ?></textarea>
     <?             
}
```

?>

Comment: first `echo $strXML` not `print_r($strXML)` because `$strXML` is a string not array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this query,

**if(sum(amount)=0,0,sum(amount))as Amount**

```
$strQuery="select Distinct DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y') as transaction_date,if(sum(amount)=0,0,sum(amount))as Amount from transactions group by  DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%c-%d-%Y')";
```

Comment: but complete month dates not shown whose stored in $dates

Comment: if () simply means that Amount will store value 0 or sum, it is not related to any thing, can u tell me if all dates are coming before using my suggestion, or can u update result for both queries.